# Symmetric positive definite matrix, why $\text{Im}(S^{-1}A) = (\text{Ker}(A))^{\bot_S}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix and $S \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ a symmetric positive definite matrix.

We note $(x,y)_S = y^T S x$ the scalar product associated to the matrix $S$ and we whrite $x \bot_S y$ if $y^T S x = 0$.

Then, I have to show that $\text{Im}(S^{-1} A)$ is included in $(\text{Ker}(A))^{\bot_S}$, and $\dim(\text{Im}(S^{-1}A)) = \text{rank}(A)$. So deduce that $\text{Im}(S^{-1}A) = (\text{Ker}(A))^{\bot_S}$.

I begin linear algebra. Someone could help me, especially for the first and second equality ? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in\textrm{im}(S^{-1}A)$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ a column vector such that:
$$y=S^{-1}Ax.$$
Let $w\in\ker(A)$, then:
$$(w,y)_S={}^\intercal wSS^{-1}A{} x={}^\intercal wAx.$$
Notice that since $A$ is symmetric, then:
$${}^\intercal({}^\intercal wA)=Aw=0.$$
Therefore, one gets $(w,y)_S=0$ so that $y\in\ker(A)^{\perp_S}$. Whence the desired inclusion.

Using rank-nullity theorem twice, one has:
$$\dim(\textrm{im}(S^{-1}A))=n-\dim(\ker(S^{-1}A))=n-\dim(\ker(A))=\textrm{rank}(A).$$
Indeed, notice that for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one has:
$$S^{-1}Ax=0\iff Ax=0,$$
so that $\ker(S^{-1}A)=\ker(A)$.